Is there a way to swap the mesh on the Unity Starter Asset Character (tutorial character) with a mesh unpacked from a prefab?
In Unity 3D, utilizing the Starter Assets package, I am trying to swap skinned mesh renderer on the characterizer game object that I duplicated in the scene. I unpacked a prefab so that I could utilize the mesh filter of the (prefab/game object). I realized that there are several meshes on the (prefab/game object) that I unpacked and wanted to know how to layer them onto the skinned mesh renderer of the starter asset character? The prefab contains multiple mesh overlays, are they layered individually onto the game object?
This is ThirdPersonController.cs
using UnityEngine;
#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM && STARTER_ASSETS_PACKAGES_CHECKED
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
#endif

/* Note: animations are called via the controller for both the character and capsule using animator null checks
 */

namespace StarterAssets
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM && STARTER_ASSETS_PACKAGES_CHECKED
    [RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerInput))]
#endif
    public class ThirdPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header("Player")]
        [Tooltip("Move speed of the character in m/s")]
        public float MoveSpeed = 2.0f;

        [Tooltip("Sprint speed of the character in m/s")]
        public float SprintSpeed = 5.335f;

        [Tooltip("How fast the character turns to face movement direction")]
        [Range(0.0f, 0.3f)]
        public float RotationSmoothTime = 0.12f;

        [Tooltip("Acceleration and deceleration")]
        public float SpeedChangeRate = 10.0f;

        public AudioClip LandingAudioClip;
        public AudioClip[] FootstepAudioClips;
        [Range(0, 1)] public float FootstepAudioVolume = 0.5f;

        [Space(10)]
        [Tooltip("The height the player can jump")]
        public float JumpHeight = 1.2f;

        [Tooltip("The character uses its own gravity value. The engine default is -9.81f")]
        public float Gravity = -15.0f;

        [Space(10)]
        [Tooltip("Time required to pass before being able to jump again. Set to 0f to instantly jump again")]
        public float JumpTimeout = 0.50f;

        [Tooltip("Time required to pass before entering the fall state. Useful for walking down stairs")]
        public float FallTimeout = 0.15f;

        [Header("Player Grounded")]
        [Tooltip("If the character is grounded or not. Not part of the CharacterController built in grounded check")]
        public bool Grounded = true;

        [Tooltip("Useful for rough ground")]
        public float GroundedOffset = -0.14f;

        [Tooltip("The radius of the grounded check. Should match the radius of the CharacterController")]
        public float GroundedRadius = 0.28f;

        [Tooltip("What layers the character uses as ground")]
        public LayerMask GroundLayers;

        [Header("Cinemachine")]
        [Tooltip("The follow target set in the Cinemachine Virtual Camera that the camera will follow")]
        public GameObject CinemachineCameraTarget;

        [Tooltip("How far in degrees can you move the camera up")]
        public float TopClamp = 70.0f;

        [Tooltip("How far in degrees can you move the camera down")]
        public float BottomClamp = -30.0f;

        [Tooltip("Additional degress to override the camera. Useful for fine tuning camera position when locked")]
        public float CameraAngleOverride = 0.0f;

        [Tooltip("For locking the camera position on all axis")]
        public bool LockCameraPosition = false;

        // cinemachine
        private float _cinemachineTargetYaw;
        private float _cinemachineTargetPitch;

        // player
        private float _speed;
        private float _animationBlend;
        private float _targetRotation = 0.0f;
        private float _rotationVelocity;
        private float _verticalVelocity;
        private float _terminalVelocity = 53.0f;

        // timeout deltatime
        private float _jumpTimeoutDelta;
        private float _fallTimeoutDelta;

        // animation IDs
        private int _animIDSpeed;
        private int _animIDGrounded;
        private int _animIDJump;
        private int _animIDFreeFall;
        private int _animIDMotionSpeed;

#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM && STARTER_ASSETS_PACKAGES_CHECKED
        private PlayerInput _playerInput;
#endif
        private Animator _animator;
        private CharacterController _controller;
        private StarterAssetsInputs _input;
        private GameObject _mainCamera;

        private const float _threshold = 0.01f;

        private bool _hasAnimator;

        private bool IsCurrentDeviceMouse
        {
            get
            {
#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM && STARTER_ASSETS_PACKAGES_CHECKED
                return _playerInput.currentControlScheme == "KeyboardMouse";
#else
return false;
#endif
            }
        }


        private void Awake()
        {
            // get a reference to our main camera
            if (_mainCamera == null)
            {
                _mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
            }
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            _cinemachineTargetYaw = CinemachineCameraTarget.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
            
            _hasAnimator = TryGetComponent(out _animator);
            _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            _input = GetComponent<StarterAssetsInputs>();
#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM && STARTER_ASSETS_PACKAGES_CHECKED
            _playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
#else
Debug.LogError( "Starter Assets package is missing dependencies. Please use Tools/Starter Assets/Reinstall Dependencies to fix it");
#endif

            AssignAnimationIDs();

            // reset our timeouts on start
            _jumpTimeoutDelta = JumpTimeout;
            _fallTimeoutDelta = FallTimeout;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            _hasAnimator = TryGetComponent(out _animator);

            JumpAndGravity();
            GroundedCheck();
            Move();
        }

        private void LateUpdate()
        {
            CameraRotation();
        }

        private void AssignAnimationIDs()
        {
            _animIDSpeed = Animator.StringToHash("Speed");
            _animIDGrounded = Animator.StringToHash("Grounded");
            _animIDJump = Animator.StringToHash("Jump");
            _animIDFreeFall = Animator.StringToHash("FreeFall");
            _animIDMotionSpeed = Animator.StringToHash("MotionSpeed");
        }

        private void GroundedCheck()
        {
            // set sphere position, with offset
            Vector3 spherePosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - GroundedOffset,
                transform.position.z);
            Grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(spherePosition, GroundedRadius, GroundLayers,
                QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

            // update animator if using character
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {
                _animator.SetBool(_animIDGrounded, Grounded);
            }
        }

        private void CameraRotation()
        {
            // if there is an input and camera position is not fixed
            if (_input.look.sqrMagnitude < _threshold || LockCameraPosition)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                //Don't multiply mouse input by Time.deltaTime;
                float deltaTimeMultiplier = IsCurrentDeviceMouse ? 1.0f : Time.deltaTime;

                _cinemachineTargetYaw += _input.look.x * deltaTimeMultiplier;
                _cinemachineTargetPitch += _input.look.y * deltaTimeMultiplier;
            }

            // clamp our rotations so our values are limited 360 degrees
            _cinemachineTargetYaw = ClampAngle(_cinemachineTargetYaw, float.MinValue, float.MaxValue);
            _cinemachineTargetPitch = ClampAngle(_cinemachineTargetPitch, BottomClamp, TopClamp);

            // Cinemachine will follow this target
            CinemachineCameraTarget.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_cinemachineTargetPitch + CameraAngleOverride,
                _cinemachineTargetYaw, 0.0f);
        }

        private void Move()
        {
            // set target speed based on move speed, sprint speed and if sprint is pressed
            float targetSpeed = _input.sprint ? SprintSpeed : MoveSpeed;

            // a simplistic acceleration and deceleration designed to be easy to remove, replace, or iterate upon

            // note: Vector2's == operator uses approximation so is not floating point error prone, and is cheaper than magnitude
            // if there is no input, set the target speed to 0
            if (_input.move == Vector2.zero) targetSpeed = 0.0f;

            // a reference to the players current horizontal velocity
            float currentHorizontalSpeed = new Vector3(_controller.velocity.x, 0.0f, _controller.velocity.z).magnitude;

            float speedOffset = 0.1f;
            float inputMagnitude = _input.analogMovement ? _input.move.magnitude : 1f;

            // accelerate or decelerate to target speed
            if (currentHorizontalSpeed < targetSpeed - speedOffset ||
                currentHorizontalSpeed > targetSpeed + speedOffset)
            {
                // creates curved result rather than a linear one giving a more organic speed change
                // note T in Lerp is clamped, so we don't need to clamp our speed
                _speed = Mathf.Lerp(currentHorizontalSpeed, targetSpeed * inputMagnitude,
                    Time.deltaTime * SpeedChangeRate);

                // round speed to 3 decimal places
                _speed = Mathf.Round(_speed * 1000f) / 1000f;
            }
            else
            {
                _speed = targetSpeed;
            }

            _animationBlend = Mathf.Lerp(_animationBlend, targetSpeed, Time.deltaTime * SpeedChangeRate);
            if (_animationBlend < 0.01f) _animationBlend = 0f;

            // normalise input direction
            Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(_input.move.x, 0.0f, _input.move.y).normalized;

            // note: Vector2's != operator uses approximation so is not floating point error prone, and is cheaper than magnitude
            // if there is a move input rotate player when the player is moving
            if (_input.move != Vector2.zero)
            {
                _targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDirection.x, inputDirection.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg +
                                  _mainCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y;
                float rotation = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, _targetRotation, ref _rotationVelocity,
                    RotationSmoothTime);

                // rotate to face input direction relative to camera position
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, rotation, 0.0f);
            }


            Vector3 targetDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, _targetRotation, 0.0f) * Vector3.forward;

            // move the player
            _controller.Move(targetDirection.normalized * (_speed * Time.deltaTime) +
                             new Vector3(0.0f, _verticalVelocity, 0.0f) * Time.deltaTime);

            // update animator if using character
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {
                _animator.SetFloat(_animIDSpeed, _animationBlend);
                _animator.SetFloat(_animIDMotionSpeed, inputMagnitude);
            }
        }

        private void JumpAndGravity()
        {
            if (Grounded)
            {
                // reset the fall timeout timer
                _fallTimeoutDelta = FallTimeout;

                // update animator if using character
                if (_hasAnimator)
                {
                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDJump, false);
                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDFreeFall, false);
                }

                // stop our velocity dropping infinitely when grounded
                if (_verticalVelocity < 0.0f)
                {
                    _verticalVelocity = -2f;
                }

                // Jump
                if (_input.jump && _jumpTimeoutDelta <= 0.0f)
                {
                    // the square root of H * -2 * G = how much velocity needed to reach desired height
                    _verticalVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * Gravity);

                    // update animator if using character
                    if (_hasAnimator)
                    {
                        _animator.SetBool(_animIDJump, true);
                    }
                }

                // jump timeout
                if (_jumpTimeoutDelta >= 0.0f)
                {
                    _jumpTimeoutDelta -= Time.deltaTime;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // reset the jump timeout timer
                _jumpTimeoutDelta = JumpTimeout;

                // fall timeout
                if (_fallTimeoutDelta >= 0.0f)
                {
                    _fallTimeoutDelta -= Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    // update animator if using character
                    if (_hasAnimator)
                    {
                        _animator.SetBool(_animIDFreeFall, true);
                    }
                }

                // if we are not grounded, do not jump
                _input.jump = false;
            }

            // apply gravity over time if under terminal (multiply by delta time twice to linearly speed up over time)
            if (_verticalVelocity < _terminalVelocity)
            {
                _verticalVelocity += Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        private static float ClampAngle(float lfAngle, float lfMin, float lfMax)
        {
            if (lfAngle < -360f) lfAngle += 360f;
            if (lfAngle > 360f) lfAngle -= 360f;
            return Mathf.Clamp(lfAngle, lfMin, lfMax);
        }

        private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
        {
            Color transparentGreen = new Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.35f);
            Color transparentRed = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.35f);

            if (Grounded) Gizmos.color = transparentGreen;
            else Gizmos.color = transparentRed;

            // when selected, draw a gizmo in the position of, and matching radius of, the grounded collider
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(
                new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - GroundedOffset, transform.position.z),
                GroundedRadius);
        }

        private void OnFootstep(AnimationEvent animationEvent)
        {
            if (animationEvent.animatorClipInfo.weight > 0.5f)
            {
                if (FootstepAudioClips.Length > 0)
                {
                    var index = Random.Range(0, FootstepAudioClips.Length);
                    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(FootstepAudioClips[index], transform.TransformPoint(_controller.center), FootstepAudioVolume);
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnLand(AnimationEvent animationEvent)
        {
            if (animationEvent.animatorClipInfo.weight > 0.5f)
            {
                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(LandingAudioClip, transform.TransformPoint(_controller.center), FootstepAudioVolume);
            }
        }
    }
}
type here

I have attempted to add a mesh filter (Man_BodyMesh) and used the root which was different on the Man-BodyMesh from the Starter Asset Mesh…….basically my object upon play looked like the vertices were jumbled resulting in The Thing from John Carpenter.

is this Ethan? or the robot?

cant you just change the mesh and add a matching animator? i dont see anything in that code that references the mesh itself. it only works with the animator in the same gameobject as this script

it is the robot.
